# Eclipse galileo project validation error causing exit workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, setup-project, galileo

I developed dynamic web project. I executed the application multiple times. But presently when i try to clean the project(Project->clean->My Project) it is showing some internal problem.. Validation of the project failed.
This is because of when  spring beans instantiation the out of memory occured.
The error message is
The stack trace is

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLStructuredRegionFactory.createRegion(XMLStructuredRegionFactory.java:31)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLSourceParser.createStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLSourceParser.java:110)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLSourceParser.parseNodes(XMLSourceParser.java:358)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLSourceParser.getDocumentRegions(XMLSourceParser.java:164)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser._core_reparse_text(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:309)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.core_reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:708)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:1352)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:1284)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.updateModel(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2705)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.internalReplaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:1919)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2415)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.set(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2927)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.setDocumentContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:579)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.initializeFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:290)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.create(ResourceFileBuffer.java:245)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.connect(TextFileBufferManager.java:113)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.FileBufferModelManager.getModel(FileBufferModelManager.java:656)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._doCommonGetModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:569)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._commonGetModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:536)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl._commonGetModel(ModelManagerImpl.java:509)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getModelForRead(ModelManagerImpl.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.validate.ValidatorGroupListener.validationStarting(ValidatorGroupListener.java:72)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager$2.run(ValManager.java:847)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.notifyGroupListenersStarting(ValManager.java:845)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.accept(ValManager.java:800)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValManager.validate(ValManager.java:667)
at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.ValBuilderJob$Visitor.visit(ValBuilderJob.java:298)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$2.visit(Resource.java:108)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:60)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)

Java Heap Space. 
Thanks in Advance.
Laxman chowdary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increase your memmory setting for eclipse. There are two ways.

1)Add extra JVM parameters while calling eclipse
2)Edit eclipse.ini. In this approach don't need to pass parameters

Open your eclipse.ini which can be found in eclipse install directory. Modify the -xmx to a higher value.

eg

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080501.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.100.v20080428-1330
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: Ref Link http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: What is the xmx value you are using?. Is your project a very big one?. Hope you have restarted eclipse after changing the xmx value.

Comment: -Xms512m   -Xmx1024m I'm using. and my project size is just 25MB only..  It working.. But taking too much time for validating spring beans.. why it is??? any idea???

Comment: It could take lot of time for validation even for mid sized project.You can turn off validation if you want. Right click the project, options , validation.